# Why is NetworkManager in disabled status?

Tags: ubuntu, networkmanager, nmcli

ubuntu 20.04 server host

Tell me why when getting nmcli status

```
nmcli general
```

I get

```
STATE         CONNECTIVITY  WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN
disconnected  unknown       enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled
```

At the same time, the NetworkManager.service service itself was successfully started. The only error in the log:

```
network manager error failed to open.run/network/ifstate
```

Indeed, there is no such file:

```
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 4096 Apr 11 14:34 if-down.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 4096 Apr 11 14:34 if-post-down.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 4096 Apr 11 14:34 if-pre-up.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 4096 Apr 11 14:34 if-up.d
```

But on another host, where the status -- connected, does not have such a file either...

Accordingly, when I run

```
nmcli connection show
```

I am getting empty output!

Comment: Network Manager is usually not used on Ubuntu servers, only on desktops. On servers it isn't even installed by default.

Comment: @Gerald Schneider As far as I know, the difference between server and desktop is only in the graphical environment. How the network settings relate to this, I do not understand.

Comment: Gerald is correct at that point. the reason for this afaik is they are stand the same with Debian and it uses /etc/network still as in the old days.